# Can anyone explain this USB ESD protection circuit?

Tags: usb, diodes

[image]

Also what are these diodes? I haven't came across them in any book yet.

Comment: Related app notes: [The Protection of USB 2.0 Applications](http://www.digikey.com/Web%20Export/Supplier%20Content/Wurth_732/PDF/Wurth_The_Protection_of_USB_20_Applications.pdf?redirected=1) by Wurth, [System-Level ESD/EMI Protection Guide](http://www.ti.com/lit/sg/sszb130b/sszb130b.pdf) by Texas Instruments, [ESD protection for USB 2.0 interfaces](http://www.nxp.com/documents/application_note/AN10753.pdf) by NXP.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Those are [transient voltage suppressor diodes.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transient-voltage-suppression_diode)
These are explicitly made to protect circuits from over voltage.

As they are installed in the USB circuit, any over voltage on the USB V+ and data lines will be shorted to the shield.

TVS diodes react fast and can conduct a lot of current for a (very) short time.  Not much good if you plug your USB into a 110V outlet, but very good for catching the short incidents caused by electrostatic discharge.

Answer (score 1):

they are ESD protection diodes, aka TVS diodes(transisent voltage suppression).

Comment: That answers the second half of the question, care to take a stab at the first half?

Comment: A tvs diode can handle a large voltage very quickly, I'm not sure of the physics behind it, to be honest. I've used them before in designs. However, since USB is being handled by people. the TVS diodes on those lines keep ESD from getting to the other end of the circuit. As soon as large (Kilovolts) esd voltage is present, the diodes conduct it to ground very quickly.